# WebStorm Javascript External Libraries - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

So I'm using Webstorm to code a Javascript Application for Overwolf. I'm using a Tumblr Wrapper that uses the Node.js library. I set the Node.Js library up in the IDE but I need to add the sources to the project itself. Is there a clean way of doing that from within the IDE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to settings click on `Node.js and NPM` under `Project Settings`, there is a section named `Sources of Node.js core modules`. You can set it up there, WebStorm automatically downloads and sets them up.